# Layered architecture and persistence annotations on the model beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j, n-tier-architecture

I would like to follow the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle in a new Java EE web app. If I understand correctly, this means that I have to keep the technical choices of my [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) (Data Access Layer) invisible from my model/business layer.

As I use Spring Data Neo4j, I must annotate my model beans with e.g. "@NodeEntity", an annotation which is specific to Spring Data Neo4J. This seems to mix the model layer with the Data Access Layer.

- Is this a good analysis I'm doing here?
- If so, how can I have a model which is independant of my DAL using Spring Data Neo4j annotations?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common solution is to apply the programming by interfaces principle, creating interfaces for each entity and relationship and implement them with SDN annotated classes.
This way the model layer would only access entities by interfaces, having no knowledge about implementation.
To astract database access operations, you can create DAO interfaces and implement them with SDN repositories and/or Cypher queries.
An example:

```
public interface Item {
    String getName();
    ...
}

public interface ItemDAO {
    Item lookup(String name);
    ...
}

@NodeEntity
public class ItemNode implements Item {
    @GraphId private Long id;
    private String name;
    ...
    public String getName() { return name; }
    ...
}

public class Neo4jItemDAO implements ItemDAO {
    ...
    @Override
    public Item lookup(String name) {
        return neo4jOperations.lookup(ItemNode.class,"name", name).to(ItemNode.class).singleOrNull();
    }
}
```

In your model class you can access entities this way:

```
@Autowired ItemDAO itemDAO;
Item item = itemDAO.lookup("name");
```

Comment: The DAO interface has the same purpose of the entity interfaces,  create a level of abstraction between the model and the data access layer. Using GraphRepository directly breaks this abstraction, exposing SDN to the model layer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of interfaces, but I still have a question. At the moment, for each model class, e.g. "User", I created a "UserRepository" interface that extends GraphRepository<User>. Do I need to create a new UserDAO interface, or is it the same thing as UserRepository interface? In other words, how standard is the GraphRepository interface of Spring Data Neo4j?

Comment: Maybe I haven't given enough details. The fact is that I have created many projects (in Eclipse), one for the user interface (UI project, which uses JSF), one for the business services, one for the business beans and one for the DAL. If I replace my beans classes with interfaces (like Item in your example), then I could move ItemNode (which is Item's Neo4j implementation) to my DAL code, which would be more logical (as it depends of Neo4j). However, will I be able to access my beans from the UI project? I don't want to create a dependency between the UI project and the DAL project.

Comment: I'm not sure I've got your point, the purpose of interfaces is to avoid dependency, using model interfaces in the UI classes is the right way to hide the DAL.

Comment: If I understand correctly, everywhere I use beans, I could use interfaces instead, even in the JSF? The question is: do I put the Neo4J-annotated beans (with @NodeEntity) inside the DAL project or do I leave them in the beans project?

Comment: I think the right place for @NodeEntity annotated classes is in the DAL project, so it will be easy to change implementation just substituting a single jar.