# Is it possible to use @Autowired on a custom interface which does not extend GraphRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I work on [a new Java EE project called ACEM](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM) that uses Spring and Spring Data Neo4j.

This question is a follow-up to "[Layered architecture and persistence annotations on the model beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20074837/1528942)", which resulted in two complementary actions :

1. Modification of [ACEM-domain-beans](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM/tree/master/ACEM-domain-beans) so that my domain is defined with interfaces instead of *Spring-Data-Neo4J-annotated* classes (implementations have been moved to the [ACEM-dao](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM/tree/master/ACEM-dao) sub-project, so that all Neo4J-specific code is in the Data Access Layer project, which is what I wanted).
2. Creation of a new DAO containing zero reference to Spring Data Neo4j.

My problem is with action 2.

At the moment, I have repositories which are, indeed, specific to SDN, for example :

```java
package eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu.neo4j;

import eu.ueb.acem.domain.beans.bleu.neo4j.BesoinNode;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.RelationshipOperationsRepository;

public interface BesoinRepository extends GraphRepository<BesoinNode>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<BesoinNode> {

}
```

If I create a BesoinDAO interface to hide this BesoinRepository interface, I guess it should look like this:

```java
package eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu;

import eu.ueb.acem.domain.beans.bleu.Besoin;

public interface BesoinDAO {

    public Besoin[] retrieveAll() throws BesoinDAOException;

    public Besoin retrieve(String name) throws BesoinDAOException;

    public void insert(Besoin besoin) throws BesoinDAOException;

    public void update(Besoin besoin) throws BesoinDAOException;

    public void delete(Besoin besoin) throws BesoinDAOException;

}
```

and then:

```java
package eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu.neo4j;

import eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu.BesoinDAO;
import eu.ueb.acem.domain.beans.bleu.neo4j.BesoinNode;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.RelationshipOperationsRepository;

public interface BesoinRepository extends BesoinDAO, GraphRepository<BesoinNode>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<BesoinNode> {

}
```

The difference is that BesoinRepository now extends BesoinDAO.

**Problem is here**

I have written a test-case which used @Autowired on BesoinRepository, and it worked fine. But if I try to get the Besoin through BesoinDAO, like below, it doesn't work anymore:

```java
@Autowired
private BesoinDAO besoinDao;

@Test
public final void t0TestCreateBesoin() {
    Besoin besoin1 = new BesoinNode("besoin1 for t0TestCreateBesoin");
    Besoin besoin2 = null;
    try {
        besoinDao.insert(besoin1);
        besoin2 = besoinDao.retrieve("besoin2 for t0TestCreateBesoin");
    } catch (BesoinDAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertNotNull(besoin2);
    }
```

Exception is:

```
Tests in error: 
t0TestCreateBesoin(eu.ueb.acem.repository.BesoinRepositoryTest): Error creating bean with name 'eu.ueb.acem.repository.BesoinRepositoryTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu.BesoinDAO eu.ueb.acem.repository.BesoinRepositoryTest.besoinDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'besoinRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property update found for type eu.ueb.acem.domain.beans.bleu.neo4j.BesoinNode
```

**Question :** is this possible to use @Autowired on an interface which is not extending SDN's GraphRepository interface? And if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem lies in generics and the fact the we have type erasure, which basically makes your `update(Besoin)` override the generic one. Try `update(<? extends Besoin> foo)` etc. But aren't you making things overly complex by trying to abstract everything?

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for your answer. Can you give me the exact line to replace my `public void update(Besoin besoin) throws BesoinDAOException;` declaration? I don't understand the <? extends Besoin> and Eclipse complains about it too (it states that _a type is expected after the token "("_). To answer your question, I agree that this may look overly complex but the project will change much in the future and I think it's worth the hassle to encapsulate every Neo4J specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces can be autowired declaring the implementing concrete classes in the Spring Data Neo4j configuration file, i.e.:

```
<bean id="besoinDao" class="eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu.neo4j.BesoinRepository"/>
```

Comment: Hi! The problem is that BesoinRepository is an interface, not a class. So I get `Error creating bean with name 'besoinDao' defined in class path resource [test-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [eu.ueb.acem.dao.bleu.neo4j.BesoinRepository]: Specified class is an interface`.

Comment: Is there any architectural benefit to have two interfaces (i.e. `BesoinRepository extends GraphRepository<BesoinNode>` and `BesoinDAO`)?

Comment: I missed it, you can use composition instead of inheritance and let BesoinRepository (or better BesoinDAO) be a class instead of an interface, it can implement the DAO interface and have an internal reference to the repository.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of embedding BesoinRepository inside [BesoinDAO](https://github.com/gcolbert/ACEM/blob/master/ACEM-dao/src/main/java/eu/ueb/acem/dao/bleu/BesoinDAO.java), it works fine and completely hides Neo4J. However I cannot choose this as the accepted answer because this is not related at all to the configuration file. :)